# VSS over internet

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I wanted to know if someone managed to make vss work over internet. Did anyone try using Hamachi? Or maybe there is other ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using hamachi to contact my VSS (TeamFoundation) and it's working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Rather depends on what you mean by "make vss work over the internet".

Given current internet speeds a simple VPN may be sufficient.

You also should look at [SourceOffSite](http://www.sourcegear.com/sos/index.html) from SourceGear - originally created in the dark ages to make VSS work over network connections that were slow (you have no idea) compared with contemporary broadband - its still valuable in that it protects you from network issues and should play nicely with Visual Studio (it certainly used to). As a former user I'd have no hesitation in recommending it.